# Is Bonjour Appropriate for Hardware communication?

Tags: ios, ios5, networking, bonjour

My networking experience to date is pretty much nil. I did some theory in college but very little hands on experience. For the past couple of weeks I've been reading up on IOS networking APIs and on more fundamental topics such as tcp /udp /dns etc.

I'm slowly beginning to absorb the information but before I venture further down my current path I'd like to know if Im looking in the right area for my purposes.

I have a hardware device that can be connected to my local network. I know for sure that others have wrote code to control this device via wifi (osc commands)from their ipads.

**Now my question:**

*Is bonjour appropriate for this type of connection or is it only really appropriate for publish / subscribe applications?*

It would help a lot to know if I'm wasting my time with bonjour or not. Also any concrete reading material on tcp connections between IOS and networked hardware would help a lot *(my google search criteria is lacking due to my lack of knowledge)*

Comment: AFAIK Bonjour is a service discovery protocol - you use it to find devices on the network but after that the actual communication protocol etc is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all lets understand what Bonjour is basically:
Bonjour is Apple’s proposal for zero-configuration networking over IP. Bonjour comes out of the work of the ZEROCONF Working Group, part of the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF). The ZEROCONF Working Group’s requirements and proposed solutions for zero-configuration networking over IP essentially cover three areas:

- Addressing (allocating IP addresses to hosts)
- Naming (using names to refer to hosts instead of IP addresses)
- Service discovery (finding services on the network automatically)

So basically Bonjour makes it easy for your applications to publish, discover, and resolve network services. There is nothing more you can do with Bonjour. Rest, the communication with other device(s), you need to handle that using Sockets(TCP Connection).

So in simple words, there is no question of appropriate or not-appropriate for hardware.

*Note: Bonjour only discovers devices on same network or same LAN.*

Comment: Its the publish, discover ,resolve network "services" that gave me doubts. Are you saying bonjour is totally fine to use to browse ip address's on my lan 'even' if the device at that address is just a device and not broadcasting a service? (Apologies for my ignorance). EG: Bonjour display ip's > I select ip and make a socket connection.

Comment: Exactly. See, with Bonjour you will be searching for a service on the network. So, if a hardware is on the same network and is not publishing any service, then the Bonjour service will query the hardware for this service and if not available, will continue to next hardware. Let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Just one more query. Do all hardware devices on a network publish "some kind" of service ? I just have to know the right one to ask bonjour to look for?

Comment: Not all of the hardware devices publish services. Some hardware publish and some may not, but still remain connected to the network.